# PHP--an Array in an Array? Not sure, using ajilion MySQLidb Class need to get value of raw Query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli, php-mysqlidb

(PHP newb here--can read code somewhat well, working on writing)

I think I have an array in an array. using this for MySQL calls:

https://github.com/ajillion/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class

my call:

```
$params = array($mta_name);
$mta_uid = $db->rawQuery("SELECT mta_uid FROM mtas WHERE mta_name = ?", $params);
echo print_r($mta_uid);
```

ends up with this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [mta_uid] => 1 ) ) 1
```

I *just* want the '1' . Have tried `mta_name['0']` and `['1']` and `['0']['1'] / ['1']['0'] / ['1']['2']` etc.

Whenever I have issues always find you guys and usually solves.  First time posting.

Many thanks!

Comment: Where did `uid` come from? Either your query has `SELECT uid` or the result should have `[mta_uid]`.

Comment: sorry for confusion.  edited and posted on personal forums--and then copied from there.   always was supposed to be mta_uid.  was just trying to simplify for personal forums.

Comment: ajilion MySQLidb Class is absolutely unusable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
echo $mta_name[0]['uid'];
```

The inner array has named elements, not simple number indexed.

Comment: wow thank you.  been struggling trying to google-fix etc for past 45 min.  it worked :)